# Using Cucumber with IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-java

Does anyone knows why 'Cucumber Java' does not appear in "Edit Configurations -> Defaults -> ???? even though my pom file as downloaded the dependency i.e. cucumber-java (1.1.5)

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.38.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Pom.xml file is used to install all the necessary plugins i.e. cucumber for java plugin

Comment: If you want to correct the answer, write it in comments to it. Try to leave it to author. Yes, you haven't rights to comment NOW, but you'll get them soon. +1 for help.

Comment: Only if the author won't react, then correct it yourself. But be really careful with it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have installed and enabled the `Cucumber for Java` plugin from the JetBrains plugin repository.

Look in the `File -> Settings...`
[image]

And you cannot install plugins into IDEA via Maven.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on top of the Answer by- Eugene.
While searching for Cucumber plugin, under File>Settings>plugins of Intellij you might not be able to see any Plugin available for cucumber and this is very weird issue for IntelliJ on windows..  troubled me for Hours..
But to solve it- we just have to click on 'Search in repositories' link as displayed on search panel. This will show all available stuff and you can select Cucumber for Java(or whatever)[image: Attaching a snap on same for better understanding.].